# Question migration

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, migration

Should the [C++ Derived classes and polymorphic dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942753/c-derived-classes-and-polymorphic-dispatching) question be migrated to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

After reading, on [Software Engineering Meta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [How do I recommend posting on another Stack Exchange site?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7569/how-do-i-recommend-posting-on-another-stack-exchange-site) I understand that I should flag the question for moderator intervention to migrate the question. But then again the question has been properly tagged for Stack Overflow.

Instead of risking "flag declined" I am trying to learn the correct way to deal with such a situation, as this is my first time for such.

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt don't migrate would be a good rule of thumb.

That particular question isn't a clear cut code review question in my opinion. Although it seems to have working code, they are asking how to apply a different structure for their derived classes. That is a programming problem that is on-topic on Stack Overflow. Questions that are on-topic don't need to be closed, let alone migrated.

Before any flagging I normally consult in the chat of the target site if the question at hand is welcome there. In the handful of attempts I think only one was indeed eligible for migration.

Migration is hard and best left to users of the target site.

Answer (score -1):

This question is on-topic on both sites.

- To be on-topic on CR, it must be complete, compile and work as intended. Which I suppose this does - I haven't tried it out. On CR it is also fine to only ask for a specific kind of review focus, such as design, performance, coding style etc.
- To be on-topic on SO, it must be sufficiently narrow, specific and contain a MCVE, which it does too.

So there is no point of migrating it, as it is already on-topic here.

The only kind of questions that should ever be migrated to CR are complete, working code where the OP does not have a specific request, but wants general feedback regarding improvements. Such questions are off-topic on SO but on-topic at CR.

Overall, the stance Stack Exchange-wide is to migrate as little as possible, as it rarely ever ends well. Most of the time it is better to close questions as off-topic and prompt the OP to ask them on another site, after adapting the question to that site's requirements.

Comment: I think you got bit by the fact that this question is now about *two* years old, and any talk of migrating it is *long* since irrelevant since things older than 60 days can't be moved.

Comment: @Makoto Yes I didn't notice that. Now what we really need are more meta dwellers running around and editing 2 year old requests to bump them on top of the page. Very helpful and meaningful.